# Warning: implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed

Tags: php, mysql, post

```
if(isset($_POST['price']))
            {
               $ret = array();
               $price=  $_POST['price'];
               array_push($ret,$price);
               $pr=count($ret);
                for($i=0; $i>$pr;$i++)
                {
                    $pri[]=$pr[$i]*$disount/100;
                    echo "<script>alert('$i'); </script>";

                }
                $nprice = implode("," , $pri);

            }
            else $nprice = '0';
```

when data is submitted it will get $_POST['price'] . In  my code i m trying apply discount on $price.As i know discount is already set . but it is giving me error ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
 Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed

Comment: $pr is not a array. It gives the count value. That variable stores only the integer. Not an array.

Comment: your for loop also troubled here. $i>$pr I think this loop can not run. You can't get any array result from this function. That null array was inputed on your implode function that why you get this error

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the $pri array before the if condition

```
$pri = array();
```

Also for the for loop, if $pr is an array the condition should be something like:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($pr);$i++)
```

Comment: This will ok but after this modification the code will not give output. Because of the forloop

Comment: Yes but he should be initializing the array to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop is actually wrong.. Change it to

```
for($i=0; $i<$pr;$i++)
          //^^ <--- Do this change..
```

Actually it should be less than operator..

You had greater than operator and thus the condition fails , so the control flow does not go inside of your `for` loop, hence the `$pri` array obviously won't be populated and thus leading to this error.

Comment: The only thing is, the first line in the for loop indicates that $pr would be an array.

Answer (score 0):

`$pri` is undefined here, so `NULL`. And `NULL` is an invalid argument to implode.

```
for($i=0; $i>$pr;$i++)
```

You seem to have used the wrong comparison sign (`<` vs. `>`), so the loop is never entered and `$pri` never set to be an array.

Fix that and for safety write `$pri = array();` before the loop to initialize it.

Comment: thanks i solved out my error but now echo "<script>alert('$i'); </script>"; result of this is 0 . But i know its $i = 2 .

Comment: @HassanAli no, it begins with 0? I don't know the value of $pr. `$i == $pr` _after_ the loop. not in the loop.